# Render multiple partials in Rails 3.2 with ajax on form submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am submitting a form to create an object with ajax in rails.
I am then appending this object to the list and it works like a charm.

In Create.js.erb:

```
$('#step_items').prepend($('<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/step_item'))     %>').fadeIn("slow"));
```

However, when I create the new step object, I am also creating a new activity object. I wanted to add the step to the steps list and the activity to the activity list. To render both partials...

I tried simply adding to create.js.erb:

```
 $('#activity_items').prepend($('<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/activity_item_in_goal')) %>').fadeIn("slow"));
```

This spits off the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/tasks/..."):
```

What is the best way to render two partials from create.js.erb? 
I am reading that you can do it through RJS, or a custom ajax call, but cannot figure it out. Can anyone provide clear example code?

Comment: What happens if you call `render(partial: 'shared/activity_item_in_goal')` instead of `render('shared/activity_item_in_goal')`?

Comment: Thank you for the response but I am still getting the same error: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/tasks/..."):

Comment: This error is happening when helpers are not able to create a path. Check if you pass the path helpers the correct variables and that they are not `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am fairly new to rails and having trouble understanding what you mean. I checked the variables and they are loading in the view normally, just not when I render through ajax.